# PEAR - why to install via CLI?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, pear

I'm a little confused about the reasoning behind installing PEAR through CLI like this (ubu ntu/debian):

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

AFAIK Pear is just PHP library - so - that's just bunch of PHP classes. So - if I need one - I just go to their website, download one, plug it into my php code - and that's it. - right? or so I think.

so - my questions are:

1) Why would I install PEAR through command line? What are the benefits over just downloading and ungzipping a package?

2) If installed through CLI - Where those packages are being installed? what dir?

Thanks:)

**UPDATE**

In retrospect - if you have the same problems with PEAR - they have been addressed by pyrus installer.
Right now - there is no need to install PEAR into single directory using apt-get or whatever. One can simply download pyrus installer (it's a single file) and install PEAR packages using pyrus installer file wherever you want. You can even have multiple PEAR packages location - no need top install it under /usr/php/pear or whatever.
makes a lot more sense than PEAR installer.

Comment: Did you download and compile the Linux kernel yourself? After all it's just a bunch of C files ;-) The question is valid anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. PEAR can resolve a package's dependencies much like `apt` does. You won't have to download dependency packages yourself.
2. On debian, that's usually `/usr/share/php`

Comment: hmm. I'm just looking into Pear itself. I didn't realize that PEAR packages had interdependencies. thanks

Comment: Indeed. PEAR could be thought of as "apt-get for PHP".